# How can I fix this Java with PostgreSQL error (table does not exist)?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, sql-insert

I work on PostgreSQL 10 and NetBeans 8.2 IDE.

I need to insert values into my Postgres table but I can't insert.

My java code.

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
String user = "postgres";
String password = "1111"; 
String status=Status,when=When,code=Code,msg=Msg,description=Description,elapsed=Elapsed,mhs_av=MHS_av,mhs_5s=MHS_5s,mhs_1m=MHS_1m,mhs_5m=MHS_5m,mhs_15m=MHS_15m,found_blocks=Found_Blocks,getworks=Getworks,accepted=Accepted,rejected=Rejected;
String hardware_errors=Hardware_Errors,utility=Utility,discarded=Discarded,stale=Stale,get_failures=Get_Failures,local_work=Local_Work,remote_failures=Remote_Failures;
String network_blocks=Network_Blocks,total_mh=Total_MH,work_utility=Work_Utility,difficulty_accepted=Difficulty_Accepted,difficulty_rejected=Difficulty_Rejected,difficulty_stale=Difficulty_Stale;
String best_share=Best_Share,device_hardware=Device_Hardware,device_rejected=Device_Rejected,pool_rejected=Pool_Rejected,pool_stale=Pool_Stale,last_getwork=Last_Getwork;

String query = "INSERT INTO SUMMARY(status,whn,code,msg,description,elapsed,mhs_av,mhs_5s,mhs_1m,mhs_5m,mhs_15m,found_blocks,get_works,accepted,rejected,"
        + "hardware_errors,utility,discarded,stale,get_failures,local_work,remote_failures,network_blocks,total_mh,work_utility,difficulty_accepted,difficulty_rejected,"
        + "difficulty_stale,best_share,device_hardware,device_rejected,pool_rejected,pool_stale,last_getwork) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
                pst.setString(1,status);
                pst.setString(2,when); pst.setString(3, code);  pst.setString(4, msg); pst.setString(5,description); pst.setString(6,elapsed); pst.setString(7, mhs_av); pst.setString(8, mhs_5s);
                pst.setString(9,mhs_1m); pst.setString(10, mhs_5m); pst.setString(11, mhs_15m); pst.setString(12, found_blocks); pst.setString(13, getworks); pst.setString(14, accepted);
                pst.setString(15, rejected); pst.setString(16, hardware_errors); pst.setString(17,utility); pst.setString(18, discarded); pst.setString(19, stale); pst.setString(20, get_failures);
                pst.setString(21, local_work); pst.setString(22, remote_failures); pst.setString(23, network_blocks); pst.setString(24, total_mh); pst.setString(25, work_utility); 
                pst.setString(26, difficulty_accepted); pst.setString(27, difficulty_rejected); pst.setString(28, difficulty_stale); pst.setString(29, best_share); 
                pst.setString(30, device_hardware); pst.setString(31, device_rejected); pst.setString(32, pool_rejected); pst.setString(33, pool_stale); pst.setString(34, last_getwork);
                pst.executeUpdate();

                } catch (SQLException ex) {

                    Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Parse.class.getName());
                    lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
```

I always get this error

> Kas 26, 2018 2:32:44 PM parse.summary sum
>   SEVERE: ERROR: relation "summary" does not exist
>     Position: 13
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "summary" does not exist
>     Position: 13
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
>       at parse.summary.sum(summary.java:46)
>       at parse.Parse.display(Parse.java:323)
>       at parse.Parse.process(Parse.java:960)
>       at parse.Parse.(Parse.java:981)
>       at parse.Parse.main(Parse.java:1007)

Comment: That Java code `String status=Status,when=When,code=Code,msg=....` won't even compile. Also: could you add a translated error message as well? Especially the part: `HATA: "summary" nesnesi mevcut değil`

Comment: I get those strings values my main class. Error text: ERROR:"summary" does not exist

Comment: The error says it all. The table 'summary' does not exist.

Comment: You should check if you have created your "summary" table - usually, you won't do that in the `postgres` database, but rather create an own database (and then adjust your connection URL)

Comment: Maybe your table is named `"SUMMARY"` rather than `SUMMARY`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: If you could post the error message in English...

Comment: Are you sure you connected to the correct database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this porblem. My table name is in the "" operation in database.

[image]

I use `\"summary\"` like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO  \"Summary\"(status,whn,code,msg,description,elapsed,mhs_av,mhs_5s,mhs_1m,mhs_5m,mhs_15m,found_blocks,get_works,accepted,rejected,"
    + "hardware_errors,utility,discarded,stale,get_failures,local_work,remote_failures,network_blocks,total_mh,work_utility,difficulty_accepted,difficulty_rejected,"
    + "difficulty_stale,best_share,device_hardware,device_rejected,pool_rejected,pool_stale,last_getwork) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The error message can be caused by several things:

1. You are connected to the wrong host, port or database, and there is no table `summary` there.
2. You are in the correct database, but the table `summary` is in a schema that is not on your [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH).
3. You are in the correct database, and `search_path` is correct, but the table is not called `summary`. Remember that PostgreSQL will fold all unquoted identifiers to lower case. So if your table is called `Summary` or `SUMMARY`, refer to it as `"Summary"` or `"SUMMARY"`.